# Select dropdown as selected using value in ng-options AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options

I am trying to set `China` as selected country but somehow it is only setting China in dropdown if I am doing like - `$scope.countrySelected = $scope.countryList[5];`

Let me know if it is possible to set value by text only as through Service I am getting `China` as a text only which I need to match.

**HTML Code -**

```
<select 
 ng-options="country.c_name for country in countryList track by country.c_id" 
 ng-model="countrySelected">
</select>
```

**SCRIPT CODE -**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.countryList = [
    {c_id: 1, c_name: 'Iran'},
    {c_id: 2, c_name: 'Iraq'},
    {c_id: 3, c_name: 'Pakistan'},
    {c_id: 4, c_name: 'Somalia'},
    {c_id: 5, c_name: 'Libya'},
    {c_id: 6, c_name: 'China'},
    {c_id: 7, c_name: 'Palestine'}
  ];

  $scope.countrySelected = 'China';
})
```

**Working Plnkr -** http://plnkr.co/edit/6qSvuuOtJHVSoNWah0KR?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method which accepts as parameter a **callback** function.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

```
$scope.countrySelected = $scope.countryList.filter(function(item){
     return item.c_name=='China';
})[0];
```

**[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bvuhKlsfwNkUDrCskiSU?p=preview)**

Also, another method is to use `find` method.

```
$scope.countrySelected = $scope.countryList.find(function(item){
     return item.c_name=='China';
});
```

For older version of browser which are incompatible with these methods you can implement your own filter method.

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(func, thisArg) {
   'use strict';
   if ( ! ((typeof func === 'Function') && this) )
      throw new TypeError();

   var len = this.length >>> 0,
   res = new Array(len), // preallocate array
   c = 0, i = -1;
   if (thisArg === undefined)
      while (++i !== len)
        // checks to see if the key was set
        if (i in this)
           if (func(t[i], i, t))
             res[c++] = t[i];
   else
      while (++i !== len)
         // checks to see if the key was set
         if (i in this)
            if (func.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t))
              res[c++] = t[i];
   res.length = c; // shrink down array to proper size
   return res;
};
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I believe its an ES6 method so won't work in IE as the app is supporting IE9

Comment: @Nesh, have a look to my answer. I used filter method now.